# Officially supported IMDB Data APIs

Tags: data-request, api

I was exploring IMDB's data APIs and came across two links.

https://developer.imdb.com/documentation/api-documentation/?ref_=side_nav

OR

https://imdb-api.com/

Do anyone known which one of these is the officially supported API from IMDB?

It appears the developers.imdb.com seems official API just by looking at the page but I prefer not to use this as it requires register an AWS account and bit of a setup here.

But the imdb-api.com looks fairly easy to setup but not sure about its performance and if anyone has used it to provide feedback?